# Matrix table to php array

Tags: php

I have some pricelist data in matrix like table that looks like this:

```
        1   2   3   4   5
1   100 200 300 400 500
2   200 400 600 800 1000
3   300 600 900 1200    1500
```

The horizontal axis are width in meters and the vertical are height in meters. The values are the price for the combination of the dimension.

How can I express that table in a PHP array?

I tried the following but something is wrong:

```
$arr = array(
array(

    "1" => 100, 
    "2" => 200, 
    "3" => 300, 
    "4" => 400, 
    "5" => 500), 
array(

    "1" => 200, 
    "2" => 400, 
    "3" => 600, 
    "4" => 800, 
    "5" => 1000), 
array(

    "1" => 300, 
    "2" => 600, 
    "3" => 900, 
    "4" => 1200, 
    "5" => 1500)
);
```

Comment: You could give your array explicit keys for the vertical, `$arr = [ 1 => [100, 200...], 2 => 200, 400...], ...]`. However, what is wrong? Please update your question to include the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the keys for the height axis (they are implicitly 0, 1, and 2):

```
$arr = [
   1 => [ 1 => 100, 2 => 200, 3 => 300, 4 => 400, 5 => 500 ],
   2 => [ 1 => 200, 2 => 400, 3 => 600, 4 => 800, 5 => 1000 ],
   3 => [ 1 => 300, 2 => 600, 3 => 900, 4 => 1200, 5 => 1500 ]
];
```

Also note that you can remove the quotes around the keys, as they are converted to integers by PHP.

Comment: And how would I reference the price of 1 by 1? Something like $arr[1][1]?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct.